# Using CompletableFuture instead of Futures for APIs

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have chance to design some async datastore-related API in Java8. I would like that my methods return promises, i.e. `CompletableFuture` instead of just `Future`. However, I haven't seen many APIs that does this (but thats maybe because they are not on java8 yet).

Would this decision be a smart one, having in mind that `CompletableFuture` are finally bringing so much  comparing to simple `Future`s?

Comment: It kind of all depends. Remember that a `CompletableFuture` _is a_ `Future`. It all comes down to what abilities you want your consumers to have.

Comment: Thats exactly a point - I don't see why anyone would use just `Future` if `CompletableFuture` is available :)

Comment: It's as you said, `CompletableFuture` is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your methods return a CompletableFuture as result, you can later decide if the computation will be done asynchronously or not -> it's just an implementation issue.

As you say, the reason why they are not (yet) being used, is because just few libraries dare to bind themselves to Java8.

As an example of a great system using the same concept, but with a better library (rxjava), have a look at Netflix: http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/02/rxjava-netflix-api.html